# Django template passing a template variable into cut filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to pass a template into a cut filter, something like this

```
{{ myVariable|cut:"something + templateVariable" }}
```

I've tried:

```
{{ myVariable|cut:"something"|add:templateVariable }}
```

and

```
{{ myVariable|cut:"something {{ templateVariable }}" }}
```

but these does not work.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should work with a temporary variable using the [with tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with myFilter="something"|add:templateVariable %}
    {{ myVariable|cut:myFilter }}
{% endwith %}
```

Or in Django 1.2 and older:

```
{% with "something"|add:templateVariable as myFilter %}
    {{ myVariable|cut:myFilter }}
{% endwith %}
```

Add does not support concatenation of string and int but you could easily make a [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that converts to string for example:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def to_unicode(mixed):
    return unicode(mixed)
```

Would allow a such template tag expression `some_int|to_unicode|add:'foo'`.

Comment: I found out it didn't work because you can't use the `add` filter to concatenate a string with an integer variable. I simply created a customer template tag to deal with that and used the code you wrote to make things simpler